# Upgrading php to 7.1 on Centos 7 misses libgmp.so.3()(64bit)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos7

I am trying to upgrade my Centos 7 server php support to version 7. Yet after I remove php 5 and try to install it, the installation fails complaining the missing libgmp.so.3()(64bit) library. Moreover there must be something strange left in the server because phpMyAdmin is gone and if I try to reinstall it a conflict is reported with:
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
How may I complete the 7 installation or at least clean it and have phpMyAdmin work again?